# 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I was trying to test Admob ads. However, it's getting an exception before the app starts

'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without AppMeasurement.

However, I have added the AppID and cocoapod

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
podfile
    target 'My App' do
      use_frameworks!
      pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
    end
```

Info.list

```
<key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
<string>ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~1458002511</string>
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize Google Mobile Ads SDK
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
    return true
}
```

Have anyone faced this issue? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#update_your_infoplist

Comment: Add the -ObjC linker flag to Other Linker Flags in your project's build settings:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is facing the problem, I am answering my own question.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start), this step is in manual download. However, that is a mandatory step to do even if you are using cocoapod.

[image]

Comment: This solution is not working for me